# What are good holidays for a disabled adult and a small child?

Tags: children, recommendations, accessibility, family

My wife had a brain haemorrhage, leaving her quite profoundly disabled. We also have a young son - he's just turned three.

What family holidays can you suggest we might be able to enjoy - both now and in the years to come?

We live in the UK and used to love visiting old cities in Europe. We also liked walking in forests and mountains, and enjoyed snowboarding.

For reference, the pertinent aspects of my wife's disabilities are as follows:

- She's a wheelchair user, and her wheelchair is slightly longer than a standard one.
- Her only real movement is in one arm, so she's totally dependent on others for mobility. She doesn't have a powered chair at the moment, but might get one in future. For now, I'm pushing her everywhere.
- She tires easily.
- She is almost completely unable to communicate, though this is improving slowly. However, she still understands perfectly what's going on around her.
- She's still her old self on the inside: all her memories, emotions, likes and dislikes are intact.

Our son is a typical three-year-old boy and enjoys all the things you'd expect. He's better-behaved than average though, which might be in our favour.

Comment: do you have a destination in mind? Is this all of Europe, or worldwide, or just in the UK/Ireland perhaps?

Comment: Can your wife travel on bus/train/ferry/plane?

Comment: We'd consider anywhere, but as she tires easily, longer journeys would be harder. Still, they might be worth it.

Right now, no - public transport would be extremely difficult. She is improving though, so let's pretend she can. I'll save those ideas for later. :)

Comment: Think about saving the money on not going on holiday to get a powered chair- freedom is worth so much.

Comment: The High Peak and Tissington Trails in the Peak District are very accessible, Parsley Hay Cycle Hire has "bikes" that are attached to the back of a wheelchair.

Comment: The powered chair thing is tricky for us unfortunately. Though she's amazing with them (she used to teach children how to drive them prior to all this, so did a perfect reverse park by her hospital bed on the first attempt), her brain damage means she doesn't notice things on her right hand side. She can see things there if you point them out, but will generally crash into / run over them. In the UK you have to pass a test before using a powered chair in public, which she wouldn't stand a chance at.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe you know it already, but might be helpful for other readers, too: [wheelmap.org](http://wheelmap.org/)

It's an OpenStreetMap where users can mark if places/buildings are wheelchair accessible. You can filter the map to only show places related to tourism.

---

Also, at least in Germany, some cities/areas have accessibility guides that list accessible hotels, free time activities etc. – some probably in German only, though. So if you'd be interested in holidays in a certain city in Germany, I could look for such info.

Answer (score 6):

The best country to visit when in a wheelchair is most likely the US. All public places have to be wheelchair-accessible, and nobody steals the designated parking spots.

What you want to visit depends on what you like most. There aren't that many old cities, of course (though e.g. Boston and San Francisco are nice), but there are plenty of amazing museums, particularly in Washington DC. And of course there's all the theme parks everywhere.

Comment: As a US citizen and a Disabled one at that, stealing designated spots, is frowned upon, but still done, and it irks those of us that need them.

Comment: @ECarterYoung: In my experience, designated parking spots are honored a whole lot more in the US than in continental Europe.